# R - ggplot - fitting large number of charts into one screen

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have data frame with cars (prices measured in 2 different periods for number of registration years for n brands). I want to analyze the dynamic of price changes, so I am trying to create a list of line charts  (x=year, y= two price series) a chart per brand.

```
# data frame example

brand=sort(rep(paste(letters[1:26]),16))
data_date  = rep(seq(as.Date("2017/5/1"), by = "month", length.out = 2 ),208)
category = rep(c(1,2),208)   
cars = data.frame(brand, data_date, category)
cars = cars[order(cars$brand,  cars$data_date, cars$category),]
year = rep(rep(seq(as.Date("2010/1/1"), by = "year", length.out = 8 ),2),26)
cars = cbind(cars, year, price= abs(rnorm(416))*10)
View(cars)
```

I created a chart using ggplot and facet_wrap and facet_grid, but the charts are hardly readable.
I tried  to use the package gridExtra and grid.arrange function, but this gives me an error which I cannot work around. 
Another alternative multiplot doesn't work with R version 3.3.3

**Can anybody explain why the grid.arrange is not working here? 

 (the same chart is printed number of times)


Is there any better way to get all the charts in one screen?**

There are my attempts:

```
load(ggplot2)

# plot 1

ggplot(data=cars , aes(x=cars$year  , y=cars$price,
                            group=interaction(cars$brand, cars$data_date),
                            fill=interaction(cars$brand, cars$data_date),
                            color =interaction(cars$brand, cars$data_date)))+
  geom_line()+  geom_point() +
  #facet_grid(.~cars$brand)
  facet_wrap(~cars$brand, ncol=2)


# plot 2 using loop

car_brands = levels(cars$brand)
p_list=list(0)

for (i in 1:26) {

  plot_data = cars[(cars$brand==car_brands[i]),]      
  p1 = ggplot(data=plot_data , aes(x=plot_data$year  , y=plot_data$price,
                                group=interaction(plot_data$brand, plot_data$data_date),
                                fill=interaction(plot_data$brand,plot_data$data_date),
                               color =interaction(plot_data$brand,plot_data$data_date)))+
    geom_line()+  geom_point() +
    facet_grid(.~plot_data$brand)+
      ggtitle(car_brands[i])

  p_list[[i]] = p1

  }

library(gridExtra)
grid.arrange(p_list, ncol=2)

Error in gList(list(list(data = list(brand = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,  : 
  only 'grobs' allowed in "gList"
```

**UPDATE**

```
grid.arrange(grobs=p_list, ncol=2)
```

worked around the error but there is still two problems with the loop approach:

**1. charts are still hardly readable 


2. the same chart is being printed number of times (what is the problem with the loop? I cannot figure out why it is not working)




 is there any better way to create this task?**

Comment: I am not seeing an issue with first run. Just move or remove legend or get a larger screen to see! And *better* way is just run multiple plots as you have quite a bit of graphs for one screen. And use *grobs* arg: `grid.arrange(grobs=p_list, ncol=2)`

Comment: ok, that seems to work, but the charts are not readable again, especially when I set ncol=1. is there anyway to force the charts to be certain size?

Comment: @ Parfait  the loop approach repeats the same chart. what is the problem with the loop?

Comment: *charts are still hardly readable*...again, you are outputting many graphs in a tight space. So of course they are unreadable. As mentioned, why not plot in multiple graphs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider `by` instead of a `for` loop as it slices your dataframe by specified factor(s) into a list of dataframes for any needed operation like `ggplot`. Also consider reducing number of graphs for readability even adjust legend and axes as below demonstrates:

```
p_list <- by(cars, cars$brand, function(b) {    
  brand_date <- interaction(b$brand, b$data_date)

  p <- ggplot(data=b, aes(x=b$year, y=b$price,
                     group = brand_date,
                     fill = brand_date,
                     color = brand_date)) +
    geom_line() + geom_point() + 
    facet_grid(.~b$brand) + labs(x="Year", y="Price") +
    theme(legend.position="bottom") +
    ggtitle(max(as.character(b$brand)))

})

# VERY LARGE PLOT
grid.arrange(grobs=p_list, ncol=2)

# FIRST 6 GRAPHS FOR BETTER READABILITY
grid.arrange(grobs=p_list[1:6], ncol=2)
```

[image: Car Brands Multiple Plot Output]

Answer (score 0):

I found the error in the 2. loop approach 
`aes_string()` was required instead of   `aes()`